# Proving an Absolute Value Inequality

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

I've just started reading Spivak's Calculus text (4th ed.) and am having some trouble on one of the exercises. The problem asks me to prove that if $|x-x_0|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|y-y_0|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then $|x-y-(x_0-y_0)|< \epsilon$. I've proven that it implies that $|x+y-(x_0 + y_0)|<\epsilon$ by adding the two given inequalities and using the addition triangle inequality for absolute value, but I can't find a way to apply the subtraction triangle inequality on this problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the inequality isn't $|x-y-(x_0-y_0)| < \epsilon$?

Comment: Ack, typo. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Hint: $|y-y_0| = |y_0-y|$

Comment: Note that $|y_0-y|\lt \frac{\epsilon}2$ and use the same method

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$|x-y-(x_0-y_0)|=|x-x_0-(y-y_0)|\le|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|\ldots$$